# Average line for 2D Histogram?

Tags: r

I am a very new user of "R" and have a question.I am currently working on making 2D Histograms on R. The material necessarily does not matter but how do I plot an average line on the 2D Histogram. The code I am running is this:

```
load("mydatabin.RData")
# Color housekeeping
library(RColorBrewer)
rf <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
r <- rf(32)

# Create normally distributed data for plotting
x <- mydata$AGE
y <- mydata$BP
df <- data.frame(x,y)

# Plot
plot(df, pch=16, col='black', cex=0.5)
```

This gives me a scatter plot and then to turn it into a 2D Histogram I do:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Default call (as object)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y))
h3 <- p + stat_bin2d()
h3

# Default call (using qplot)
qplot(x,y,data=df, geom='bin2d')
```

After this I do:

```
h3 <- p + stat_bin2d(bins=25) + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=r)
h3
```

to add color.

Therefore, from here how do I plot an average line of the data.

And if anyone can tell me how to plot a heat map that looks like this using mydatebin.RData:

[image: heat map plot]

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "average line"? What are the properties that this line would have?

Comment: What I mean by an average line is kind of like for the picture for this link: "http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27134-plot-average-line" but just for a 2D Histogram. Like I said I'm really new to R, so I'm not sure what properties it should have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_hline` or `geom_vline` in `ggplot2`, passing y/xintercept as a parameter to draw a line. In your case, the parameter can be an average of one of your column to draw an average line. See the code for the example.
I also played around and tried two different ways to draw 2D histograms. Yours seems better and more precise, though I removed colorBrewer.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create normally distributed data for plotting
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

# stat_density2d way, with average lines
p1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="navy", high="yellow") +
  # Here go average lines
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$y), color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(df$x), color = "red") +
  # Just to remove grid and set background color
  theme(line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "navy"))
p1
```

[image]

```
# stat_bin2d way, with average lines
p2  <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  stat_bin2d(bins=50) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="navy", high="yellow") +
  # Here go average lines
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(df$y), color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(df$x), color = "red") +
  # Just to remove grid and set background color
  theme(line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "navy"))
p2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This really helped!!

Comment: Is there anyway that I can change the labels for x and y to say any title I want?

Comment: Sure. It is basic functionality of ggplot2, so you probably need to read an introduction, for example, here: http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html
Specifically on titles, just add the code `+
  xlab("Your x axis title")+
  ylab("Y axis title") +
  ggtitle(label = "YOLO")` to your ggplot piece. Read more: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html

Comment: Thanks again, I've been trying to read about R as much as I can. My problem is with the application. Thank you for the help and the tutorial, I will make sure to look at them.